# What are best practices in Setting up Localization in an ASP.NET Web Application Project in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, localization

I feel like i am completely missing something because I am not able to find any examples describing what i want to do.

I have a fairly plain jane ASP.NET web application project that I want to localize.  I'd like the output to have satellite dlls so that later when I want to add a language I can just drop in a new DLL.

I have created resx files under App_GlobalResources for the default culture and spanish.  When I compile tho, I am not getting a subdirectory under my bin for ES.

If i want to add German or French in the future without a recompile of my web app, how is this done?

Many things are pointing to AL.exe but I haven't seen any example of anyone using it in an ASP.NET application.  I'm not finding any articles indicating how to set up a localized project/solution in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was happening.  After I used visual studio to add a new resources file, it added it with a build action of content.   If changed to Embedded resource, the x.resources.dll will be built in the correct culture directory.   You should also set the Access Modifier to public (I'm pretty sure this is necessary or your main dll won't be able to connect to the culture resource).   This will have the effect of changing the Custom Tool property to PublicResXFileCodeGenerator.